# PDO breaking time_ago function

Tags: php

Im currently in the process of converting my site over to PDO but ive hit a little snag, i have a function that converts a datetime into text saying how long ago it was posted, but after changing my query to PDO the function is throwing me an error:

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: retval in C:\wamp\www\pdoconvert\threads.php on line 301 (line 20 of the function)
```

Function:

```
function time_ago($date,$granularity=2) {
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $difference = time() - $date;
    $periods = array('decade' => 315360000,
        'year' => 31536000,
        'month' => 2628000,
        'week' => 604800, 
        'day' => 86400,
        'hour' => 3600,
        'minute' => 60,
        'second' => 1);
    if ($difference < 5) { // less than 5 seconds ago, let's say "just now"
        $retval = "Posted just now";
        return $retval;
    } else {                            
    foreach ($periods as $key => $value) {
        if ($difference >= $value) {
            $time = floor($difference/$value);
            $difference %= $value;
            $retval .= ($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' ';        <-- Line 301
            $retval .= (($time > 1) ? $key.'s' : $key);
            $granularity--;
        }
        if ($granularity == '0') { break; }
    }
    return ' Posted: '.$retval.' ago';      
    }
}
```

Query:

```
$nostmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT threads.Thread_ID, threads.Thread_Title, threads.Board_ID, threads.Author, threads.Thread_Sticky, threads.Thread_Locked, Sub1.LatestPost, Sub1.PostCount, members.Post_As, members2.Member_ID AS LastPostMemberID, members2.Post_As AS LastPostMemberPostAs
        FROM threads 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Thread_ID, MAX(posts.Post_DateTime) AS LatestPost, COUNT(*) AS PostCount FROM posts GROUP BY Thread_ID) Sub1
        ON threads.Thread_ID = Sub1.Thread_ID
        INNER JOIN members 
        ON threads.Author = members.Member_ID
        INNER JOIN posts posts2
        ON posts2.Thread_ID = Sub1.Thread_ID AND posts2.Post_DateTime = Sub1.LatestPost
        INNER JOIN members members2
        ON members2.Member_ID = posts2.Member_ID
        WHERE threads.Board_ID=:Board_ID 
        AND threads.Thread_Sticky='0'
        ORDER BY Sub1.LatestPost DESC
        LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage");
$nostmt->bindValue( ":Board_ID", $Board_ID);
$nostmt->execute();
while($row = $nostmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $Thread_ID = $row['Thread_ID']; 
    $Thread_Title = $row['Thread_Title'];   
    $Board_ID = $row['Board_ID'];       
    $Author = $row['Author']; 
    $Thread_Sticky = $row['Thread_Sticky'];  
    $Thread_Locked = $row['Thread_Locked'];  
    $Post_Author = $row['Post_As']; 
    $Posts = $row['PostCount']; 
    $Post_DateTime = time_ago($row['LatestPost']);  <--time-ago function called
    $Member_ID = $row['LastPostMemberID']; 
    $Post_As = $row['LastPostMemberPostAs'];
```

what really confuses me is i get this error twice per outputted row but i also get the correct time-ago output aswell.

how should i go about fixing this? is it my shoddy PDO conversion or a fault with the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$retval` variable isn't defined at that point(`line 301`).

To solve this:

- Define the `$retval` variable on the first line of the function `$retval="";`

or

- Remove the concatenation from the line `301` `$retval=($retval ? ' ' : '').$time.' ';`

**I recommend to use the first option**

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$retval` without having initialized it first, that is why you get a notice. Try to initialize it (to an empty string for example) at the top of your function. You could also remove the concatenation dot on line 301 to the same effect.

Notices in PHP are not errors. They are meant to warn you about potentialy harmful constructs that may cause errors later if you didn't write them purposefuly. Notices can be disabled in php.ini though, and are by default. The line in php.ini looks like this :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```